# Error occurred while executing Dynomodb query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Here, is my configuration:

```
Table Name: MY_TABLE
Primary partition key   method (String)
Primary sort key    path (String)
```

and I would like to query agains two fields:

```
1. method (Primary partition key): GET
2. path (Primary sort key): /greet/v1/hello
```

I have used '#pathKey' because 'path' is a reserved keyword. (Similar for #methodKey)

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name MY_TABLE \
--key-condition-expression '#pathKey=:path1 AND #methodKey=:method1' \
--expression-attribute-names '{"#pathKey":"path"}' \
--expression-attribute-names '{"#methodKey":"method"}' \
--expression-attribute-values '{":method1":{"S":"GET"}}' \
--expression-attribute-values '{":path1":{"S":"/greet/v1/hello"}}'
```

But while doing so, I am getting the below error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: An expression attribute name used in the document path is not defined; attribute name: #pathKey
```

Please note that, I don't want to use an external JSON file to pass parameters and needs to run on command line.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide all expression attribute names under the same CLI argument (also true for the values).

What happened is that `--expression-attribute-names '{"#methodKey":"method"}'` override the one before. Hence, the error is regarding missing `#pathKey`.

It should work for you this way:

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name MY_TABLE \
--key-condition-expression '#pathKey=:path1 AND #methodKey=:method1' \
--expression-attribute-names '{"#pathKey":"path", "#methodKey":"method"}' \
--expression-attribute-values '{":path1":{"S":"/greet/v1/hello"}, ":method1":{"S":"GET"}}'
```

Comment: I tried your solution but now it gives this error: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: An expression attribute name used in the document path is not defined; attribute name: #pathKey

Comment: it's the same one you mentioned in the question

Comment: Yes, I did ask the question